# Integrating SFML-VScode-boilerplate with ImGui

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, sfml, imgui

I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/2YS5WJTeKpI) in order to use ImGui with [sfml-vscode-boilerplate](https://github.com/rewrking/sfml-vscode-boilerplate) on VScode (macOS). However, the content of this [video](https://youtu.be/2YS5WJTeKpI) is about integrating ImGui with SFML in Visual Studio. So I could not repeat every process in that video.

When I executed Program by pressing Ctrl+Shift+B and click on the Build & Run Debug option, I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7pM8.png)

```
⬤  Build & Run: Debug (target: IMGUISFML)


⇛  Linking: bin/Debug/IMGUISFMLUndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ImGui::End()", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(sf::Window const&, sf::Event const&)", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::SFML::Render(sf::RenderWindow&)", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::SFML::Update(sf::RenderWindow&, sf::Time)", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::SFML::Shutdown()", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::Begin(char const*, bool*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
  "ImGui::Button(char const*, ImVec2 const&)", referenced from:
      _main in Main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [bin/Debug/IMGUISFML] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

✘  Failed!
   Review the compile errors above.

The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'bash ./build.sh buildrun Debug vscode'" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Here is my file structure. (This folder is identical to [sfml-vscode-boilerplate](https://github.com/rewrking/sfml-vscode-boilerplate), except imgui folder is added.)

- .vscode

  - _keybindings.json
  - c_cpp_properties.json
  - launch.json
  - settings.json
  - tasks.json
- bin
- content
- env
- imgui

  - imconfig-SFML.h
  - imconfig.h
  - imgui_draw.cpp
  - imgui_internal.h
  - imgui_tables.cpp
  - imgui_widgets.cpp
  - imgui-SFML_export.h
  - imgui_SFML.cpp
  - imgui_SFML.h
  - imgui.cpp
  - imgui.h
  - imstb_rectpack.h
  - imgstb_textedit.h
  - imgstb_truetype.h
- lib
- src

  - Platform
  - Utility
  - Main.cpp
  - PCH.hpp
- test
- .clang-format
- .gitignore
- build.sh
- Makefile
- README.md

```cpp
//Here is "Main.cpp" file
#include "../imgui/imgui.h"
#include "../imgui/imgui-SFML.h"

#include "Platform/Platform.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "ImGui + SFML = <3");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    //ImGui::SFML::Init(window);

    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    sf::Clock deltaClock;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            ImGui::SFML::ProcessEvent(window, event);

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        ImGui::SFML::Update(window, deltaClock.restart());

        ImGui::Begin("Hello, world!");
        ImGui::Button("Look at this pretty button");
        ImGui::End();

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        ImGui::SFML::Render(window);
        window.display();
    }

    ImGui::SFML::Shutdown();
}
```

What should I do in order to integrate SFML with ImGui on VScode (macOS). Also, if ImGui is not available, is there another free recommended alternative C++ GUI Library?

Thank you for reading my message.

Comment: Linker errors like these stem from failing to compile and link all relevant files together. You need to check your build command/system to ensure that it includes all those files

Comment: Your `tasks.json` is likely the source of the linker errors. You will have to investigate that.

Comment: Alas, I have not used Dear ImGui and SFML together, but have you seen this library? https://github.com/eliasdaler/imgui-sfml